# Can we measure gravitational constant at high accuracy using a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, experimental-physics, measurements

It is extremely difficult to fetch accurate value of gravitational constant. How about we have a black hole toy and laboratory for it? I am (currently) not a university student and need help for it.

Comment: What is a “black hole toy”?

Comment: Why would having a black hole help?

Comment: black hole toy is just a black hole

Comment: What exactly is your method for using a black hole to measure the gravitational constant ?

Comment: Humanity currently cannot make black holes at all, and has not yet found any smaller than 3.8 solar masses, or nearer than 5200 light-years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. To measure G, you must have independent measurements of mass and gravitational field. The mass of the black hole can only be inferred from its gravity.

Comment: +1. Could you have a planet and the black hole orbit their mutual center of mass, and infer the black hole mass from the radius of its orbit?

Comment: @mmesser314 How, then, would you measure the mass of the planet?

Comment: @mmesser314 No, because there is no analytic solution for a two-body system in GR. So the result would not be of high accuracy.

Comment: @safesphere No analytic solution, does not imply no highly accurate solution. Some aspects of orbital dynamics around a black hole have been calculated with thousands (!) of digits of accuracy.

Comment: I agree with @TimRias (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic) but how to find that data?

Comment: @TimRias Are you saying that numerical gravity can produce a high accuracy result for a realistic two body problem? Even if this were the case, you would not know the density distribution of the real planet and therefore the actual stress-energy tensor. Plus a real black hole would be spinning with an accretion disk that would is described by the vacuum Kerr solution. So calculating a real binary system with numerical gravity to a high precision is a just pipe dream.

Comment: @safesphere Perhaps you're right for close orbits, but gravity has long range. See https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/orbits.html for *extremely* accurate orbital simulations.

Comment: @safesphere How much accuracy can be achieved (and through what method) depends the orbital separation of the binary, the mass-ratio, compactness of the object orbitting the black hole. For example, of the object is compact and small enough, its internal composition would not be relevant for high accuracy calculation. All this is moot though, since no matter how accurate the simulation data, you would still not be able to measure G.

Comment: @safesphere You don't actually *need* to do a 2 body calculation. Photon trajectories around a Schwarzschild black hole can be computed using $\phi=\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{b^{-2}-u^2+u^3}}$, where $u=r_s/r$ and $b\cdot r_s$ is the impact parameter. That's an elliptic integral of the 1st kind, which can be rapidly calculated to high precision using the arithmetic-geometric mean. See [Carlson (1994)](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.math/9409227) for details.

Comment: @PM2Ring: to be hyper-pedantic (because I know it doesn't *really* matter, you're neglecting the back-reaction of the photon onto the spacetime, so you're still taking the same geometric approximation you use when you treat schwarzschild as a background for computing planetary orbits.

Comment: @Jerry Mea culpa, although I did mention "that critical impact parameter calculation ignores the spacetime curvature caused by the photon itself" in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25552/can-light-be-trapped-in-orbit/50275#comment111574_50275 OTOH, I expect that the error in the measurement of the potential energy of the chunk of matter that we drop into the BH is larger than the errors due to the photon energy.

Answer (score 3):

This is fundamentally impossible.

In the metric for the black hole, $G$ only ever appears in the combination $GM$. Consequently, there is no way of interacting with a black hole that will allow you to independently measure the mass $M$ and $G$.

The same is true for the dynamics of a black hole binary. G will always be paired with one of the masses (and vice versa).

Not coincidentally, the same is true in Newtonian gravitational physics, which is why we know $GM_{\odot}$ very accurately, but not G.

Comment: I disagree that it's *fundamentally* impossible, but it's surely not possible in practice. You "simply" need to measure $r_s$ of the BH (eg by determining the photon sphere radius via photon deflection), drop a chunk of matter of known mass into the BH, then measure the new $r_s$. Of course, other sources of gravitational potential must be negligible, and to convert the observer's measurements to Schwarzschild coordinates you have to account for the spacetime curvature in their vicinity (and their velocity).

Comment: @PM2Ring Clever.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. In general relativity $G$ can be derived from the knowledge of Einstein's gravitational constant $\kappa$ and $c$, the propagation velocity of gravitation waves. See my answer to the question [Is the Planck force a truly "Planck unit"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/707944).

Comment: While yes, energy loss due to gravitational waves is definitely proportional in magnitude to $G$, we can barely measure it as is, so I doubt you'll be able to beat cavendish-style experiments that way.

Comment: I have rather thought of Planck force (~$c^4/G$) measurement. In principle it should be possible to determine $\kappa$ in the strong gravitation limit. Imagine Einstein living at the center of star on the verge to become a black hole. He would develop theory of spacetime (GR) without need or use of Newton's constant.